# Python pandas how to use a lamda function to convert duplicated code in 1 line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas python code like this:

```
def mul3(df):
    df['mul31'] = df['tpx1'].values * df['tqy1'].values * df['vtin1'].values * df[
        'slife1'].values
    df['mul32'] = df['tpx2'].values * df['tqy2'].values * df['vtin2'].values * df[
        'slife1'].values
    df['mul33'] = df['tpx3'].values * df['tqy3'].values * df['vtin3'].values * df[
        'slife1'].values
    df['mul34'] = df['tpx4'].values * df['tqy4'].values * df['vtin4'].values * df[
        'slife1'].values
    df['mul35'] = df['tpx5'].values * df['tqy5'].values * df['vtin5'].values * df[
        'slife1'].values
    return df
```

Is there anyway I can use a lamda function to replace it to 1 line code?
Any friend can help?

Comment: You have a lot of `slife1` - did you mean to do `slife1`, `slife2`, `slife3`, etc.?

Comment: Not it is the same slife1

Comment: I would suggest using a for loop to solve this problem: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly like @richardec's solution. The only difference is it uses a dict comprehension and `assign`.

```
df = df.assign(**{f'mul3{i}': df[f'tpx{i}'] * df[f'tqy{i}'] * df[f'vtin{i}'] * df['slife1'] for i in range(1,6)})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works,what dose ** mean here ?

Comment: @William it’s the dictionary unpacking operator. Dict comprehension creates a dictionary and we assign to multiple columns at once by unpacking it inside the assign method.

Comment: @William btw, please consider upvoting my answer if you found it helpful and please consider accepting richardec’s answer instead since they got a working solution first.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do it like this:

```
N = 5
df[[f'mul3{i}' for i in range(1, N+1)]] = [df[f'tpx{i}'].values * df[f'tqy{i}'].values * df[f'vtin{i}'].values * df['slife1'].values for i in range(1, N+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a one-liner but much more readable

```
func = lambda df, num : df[f'tpx{num}'].values * df[f'tqy{num}'].values * df[f'vtin{num}'].values * df[f'slife1'].values
for i in range(5):
    df[f'mul3{i}'] = func(df, i)
```